# Binding obj-c typedef function

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to do my first obj-c -> C# binding and I'm stuck with a typedef binding.

Basically, I've been able to bind whole file with Objective-Sharpie but it didn't pull this one type over.

```
@class LCLineChartDataItem;

typedef LCLineChartDataItem *(^LCLineChartDataGetter) (NSUInteger item);


@interface LCLineChartDataItem : NSObject

@property (readonly) float x; /// should be within the x range
@property (readonly) float y; /// should be within the y range
@property (readonly) NSString *xLabel; /// label to be shown on the x axis
@property (readonly) NSString *dataLabel; /// label to be shown directly at the data item

+ (LCLineChartDataItem *)dataItemWithX:(float)x y:(float)y xLabel:(NSString *)xLabel dataLabel:(NSString *)dataLabel;

@end


@interface LCLineChartData : NSObject

@property (strong) UIColor *color;
@property (copy) NSString *title;
@property NSUInteger itemCount;

@property float xMin;
@property float xMax;

@property (copy) LCLineChartDataGetter getData;

@end
```

The typedef is my only problem at this point and I'm not really sure how to define it in C#.
I did find this but I'm not sure how to apply it: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_types_reference_guide/#BlockCallback

Any help to take me forward, would be appreciated

P.s. I'm trying to make a binding of https://github.com/mruegenberg/ios-linechart

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I also need to know how to use it in LCClineChartData.getData .